# New-URN for enterprise yang module

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I am developing enterprise yang module. I have a registered domain name.Do i need to registered top-level URN to the iana for yang data module's namespace like urn:rdns::  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what [RFC6020, Section 5.3.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-5.3) says about namespaces:

> Namespaces for modules published in RFC streams [RFC4844] MUST be
> assigned by IANA, see Section 14.

> Namespaces for private modules are assigned by the organization
> owning the module without a central registry.  Namespace URIs MUST be
> chosen so they cannot collide with standard or other enterprise
> namespaces, for example by using the enterprise or organization name
> in the namespace.

Note the last paragraph. Enterprise modules are assigned URIs that are chosen and governed by the enterprise. So no, you do not need to register with a central repository, not from YANG's point of view. The same text applies to both YANG 1 and [1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netmod-rfc6020bis-14#section-5.3).

There is a [proposal](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/netmod/current/msg15801.html) on NETMOD mailing list for a top-level RDNS for enterprise modules, but that is just that, a proposal.